# iOS export of Unity-Vuforia project crashes on initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm currently working on an AR project for mobile using the Vuforia engine package in Unity.
The project works fine on the Unity Editor and when i export it to Android Studio.
However when i export it on XCode for iOS, Unity launches correctly but then i get an execution error message from Vuforia.

See error screenshot:

[image]

I currently use Unity 2020.3.29f1, Vuforia 10.12.3 and XCode 14.2, i do test the project on an Iphone 14 pro simulator with iOS 16. I have tried upgrading and downgrading Unity and Vuforia versions. I also have tried creating an new empty Unity project and adding the Vuforia package (so that Vuforia get's initialized on start), none of that works. I know the problem comes from vuforia because i tried exporting an previous unity project of mine that doesn't use Vuforia and it directly worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Vuforia didn't support iOS simulator as of 2018 and i'm guessing it's still the case, i don't have a device to test whether that's where the problem comes from or not. I'll post an update when i can.
[vuforia forum](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/error-when-building-ios)

[**UPDATE**]

I have tried the app on a physical iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 16.2 and it worked directly, i think it's safe to say Vuforia still doesn't accept iPhone simulators

[Photo of the working app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCJ6d.jpg)